# How to specify a row delimiter in pandas read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas

I would use a different row delimiter than `\n` with `pandas.read_csv()`. Does anyone know how to do that?

In the documentation of `read_csv()`, I found nothing related, but in the `to_csv()` page, I found the parameter `line_terminator`.

How may I solve this problem?

Comment: There is too `lineterminator` parameter

Comment: `pd.read_csv(filename, lineterminator=delimiter)` ?

Comment: Wow, ok. I don't know why, I didn't found this field.

Comment: Trying to modify the code, by using the  `lineterminator` parameter, the python interpreter tells me that:
 `ValueError: Custom line terminators not supported in python parser (yet)`

Comment: What is your delimiter?

Comment: It can only be a single character

Comment: Ok, I found the problem: the field does not allow a string longer than 1 character. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: I've tried by using the `lineterminator` equal to `chr(254)`, equal to `chr(255)` or equal to `chr(256)`. For the first case, it gives me the same error (`ValueError: Custom line terminators not supported in python parser (yet)`), but it should not. Instead for the other two cases, it crashes as expected, since the text is parsed in `UTF-8`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212067/discussion-between-carmine-and-mohit-motwani).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an Example:

File: a.csv

```
hello,world:hell,worl:hel,wor:he,wo
```

```
a = pd.read_csv('a.csv', lineterminator=':')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
    hello world
  0  hell  worl
  1   hel   wor
  2    he    wo
```